# How to concat several rows in pandas dataframe into 1 row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to concat several rows (up to 10) in pandas dataframe to a single row.

For example:
I have such dataframe

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

convert to

```
   a_0  b_0  a_1  b_1 
0  1    3    2    4
```

Merging row by row is stupid, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex Series`, convert to one row DataFrame and last flatten `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.stack().to_frame().T
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}')
print (df)
   a_0  b_0  a_1  b_1
0    1    3    2    4
```

Or if all values are numeric use [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from  itertools import product

c = [f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}' for x in product(df.columns, df.index)]
df = pd.DataFrame([df.to_numpy().ravel()], columns=c)
print (df)
   a_0  a_1  b_0  b_1
0    1    3    2    4
```